# Mouse cursor doesn't hide in monogame on windows even when IsMouseVisible set to false

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I have a windowed app. By default the mouse cursor is visible.

However I wish to implement my own mouse cursor.

In the initialise method, I have done:

`IsMouseVisible = false;`

However this does not work.

Google suggests that the cursor is hidden by default, however this does not appear to be true.

Locking the mouse input to the window would also be acceptable, so you have to press alt-tab or ESC to unlock it, however I can't find a way to do that either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll leave this answer here on the off-chance someone else hits this issue although it's rather stupid.

I'm developing on a remote machine, using TeamViewer. On TeamViewer (and likely other solutions) the mouse cursor is always visible.

The above code works fine to hide it.